# Why some packages are upgradable in Pip, not in Conda?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I installed Anaconda under Windows 10. Everything is working fine. I also ran

```
conda upgrade --all
```

in a command prompt.

However, I noticed that when I type this in a command prompt:

```
pip list -o
```

I get (among other things)

```
astroid (1.4.7) - Latest: 1.4.8 [wheel]
```

This means package `astroid` is upgradable under pip. However, when I go to the Anaconda Navigator and look at the list of upgradable packages I do not see `astroid` in it. (I was not able to find a command line way of seeing which packages are upgradable under Conda).

Can someone explain why `astroid` appears as upgradable under Pip and not under Conda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [package list maintained by Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) is different than that of [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). It seems that [`astroid`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astroid) is not yet updated in the Anaconda package list.

You can either wait until the update is available in Anaconda, or you can [temporarily use the version available via `pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34181609/189134) by uninstalling the conda version and installing the pip one:

```
conda remove astroid
pip install astroid
```

When Anaconda has updated, reverse those two commands to switch back:

```
pip uninstall astroid
conda install astroid
```

Comment: In some posts on the web I saw that there are two pips, one from Anaconda and the "original" one (or something like that). If I just type `pip install astroid` like you suggested will it be the "right" pip? (Sorry if this is a bit confusing but I am a beginner)

Comment: @Soldalma `pip` should always refer to the correct executable for your Conda environment, so you should be fine to use that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Anaconda hasn't updated `astroid` yet - their [package list](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) shows it as only available for v1.4.7 (select Python 3.5 in the top tab and Ctrl+F `astroid`, or look [on this page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astroid/1.4.8)). However, `astroid` have updated the [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astroid/1.4.8) repository where Pip fetches packages from, so v1.4.8 is available through Pip and not through Anaconda.

As for why the package hasn't been upgraded - I'm not quite sure. There's been plenty of time since the release and there's no explanation *why* they wouldn't upgrade, so I can't really tell. Installing via pip should be fine if you need the latest version, though.

Comment: My guess is that an abstract syntax tree is not very important to the needs of the typical `Anaconda` user, so updating it to the latest version is lower priority.